Setup FreeRTOS project with multiple CPUs
I'm new to FreeRTOS.
I'm using a Xilinx FPGA with multiple Microblaze CPUs to implement a PCIe controller. The controller is fully functional and the code on each CPU runs on bare metal. I now want to run FreeRTOS on just one of the CPUs.
I initially created a FreeRTOS demo application with just 1 CPU with an AXI Timer and Interrupt controller. The project worked fine.
I now want to create my actual project with 10 CPUs, with only one of them running FreeRTOS. Each CPU has its own BSP. I'm using Xilinx Vitis IDE v2020.2.0 (64-bit) on Linux. How do I create such a project?
I've spent a lot of time trying to figure this out and Googled for it but have been unsuccessful, so would be grateful for any pointers.
TIA
